# Aggregate $filter Between Elements Matching Conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

---

Data:

```
[

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597c48d222b29fc421e82d20"),
    "Date" : "12/06/2017",
    "Country" : "DEMO",
    "RiderId" : "DEMO",
    "VehicleId" : "DEMO",
    "StartAddress" : "Colombo",
    "StartLocation" : [ 
        6.9270974, 
        79.8612478
    ],
    "EndAddress" : "Kegalle,",
    "EndLocation" : [ 
        7.2476005, 
        80.3483415
    ],
    "DepartureAddress" : "Dellogistics International (Pvt) Ltd, Colombo 04",
    "DepartureLocation" : [ 
        6.8824893, 
        79.8620031
    ],
    "ArrivalAddress" : "Osro, Kegalle",
    "ArrivalLocation" : [ 
        7.2476005, 
        80.3483415
    ],
    "IsLadiesOnly" : false,
    "Notes" : "\"I'm travalleing from Bambalapitiya to Kegalle, small luggages are ok\"",
    "Luggage" : 2.0,
    "Detours" : 1.0,
    "Route" : {
        "Bounds" : {
            "NorthEast" : [ 
                7.2916216, 
                80.6341326
            ],
            "SouthWest" : [ 
                6.9270974, 
                79.8607731
            ]
        },
        "Legs" : [ 
            {
                "LegId" : 0.0,
                "Distance" : 40033.0,
                "Duration" : 4725.0,
                "Price" : "240",
                "StartAddress" : "Colombo",
                "StartLocation" : [ 
                    6.9270974, 
                    6.9270974
                ],
                "EndAddress" : "Nittambuwa",
                "EndLocation" : [ 
                    7.1420863, 
                    80.1038061
                ],
                "Ancestors" : []
            }, 
            {
                "LegId" : 1.0,
                "Distance" : 18008.0,
                "Duration" : 1850.0,
                "Price" : "480",
                "StartAddress" : "Nittambuwa",
                "StartLocation" : [ 
                    7.1420863, 
                    80.1038061
                ],
                "EndAddress" : "Warakapola",
                "EndLocation" : [ 
                    7.2268383, 
                    80.1959644
                ],
                "Ancestors" : [ 
                    "Colombo"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "LegId" : 2.0,
                "Distance" : 22478.0,
                "Duration" : 2208.0,
                "Price" : "720",
                "StartAddress" : "Warakapola",
                "StartLocation" : [ 
                    7.2268383, 
                    80.1959644
                ],
                "EndAddress" : "Kegalle",
                "EndLocation" : [ 
                    7.2514362, 
                    80.3466076
                ],
                "Ancestors" : [ 
                    "Colombo", 
                    "Nittambuwa"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "CreatedDate" : "2017-01-06T07:00:00.000Z",
    "ModifiedDate" : "01/06/2017 12:30",
    "Points" : "123"
}]
```

And the query is :

```
 db.trips.aggregate([
       {$match: { "Route.Legs": { $elemMatch: { "StartAddress": "Nittambuwa","Ancestors":{$nin:["Kegalle"]}} }, "Route.Legs.EndAddress":"Kegalle" }},
        {  $project: {
             RiderId: "$RiderId",
             Legs: {
                $filter: {
                   input: "$Route.Legs",
                   as: "leg",
                   cond: {
                          "$and": [
                            { "$gte": [ "$$leg.LegId", <**Get the leg id by passing the  start address**> ] },
                            { "$lte": [ "$$leg.LegId", 3 ] }
                          ]
                        }
                }
             }
          }}

    ])
```

Basicaly inside the condition i need to query the collection and get the leg ID for comparison. i tried $where but it doesn't recognize the operator inside the condition.

Also why i cannot use $where, $nin inside the cond

Comment: Any reasons for the -1.  Is the question stupid??

Comment: Probably because you actually did not supply any data when the question was asked, and even now that you have the format does not match the aggregation expression posted. Also [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is kind of documented and the reasons why you cannot use it should be pretty apparent (not that you should even consider it in the first place). If you expect some help then you need to supply data that actually relates to the expression you are running. Or "attempting" to run at least.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry my bad. i wanted to keep the data to minimal and had posted the wrong code. I've updated the data. any suggestions on this.?

Comment: Nothing wrong with keeping it minimal as long as the same fields and structure a relevant you need only include those actually addressed by the query. Speaking of, it seems you last edit now means that the provided document actually does not meet the "criteria" of the query anyway. Or at least the query that **was posted** because that is **missing as well**. This is in fact generally why you receive downvotes, which was what I was trying to explain to you. Please try and pay attention, otherwise people will treat you accordingly.

Comment: @NeilLunn My bad again :(.. verified and updated :P

Comment: MongoDB version???

Comment: mongo version 3.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally need to apply the condition by nesting another [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) within the outer [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) which looks up the matching array entry and matches the conditions. Then applying [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to actually supply the `"LegId"` value for the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) condition:

```
db.trips.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "Route.Legs": { 
      "$elemMatch": { 
        "StartAddress": "Nittambuwa",
        "Ancestors":{ "$nin": [ "Kegalle" ] }
      }
    }, 
    "Route.Legs.EndAddress":"Kegalle" 
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "RiderId": 1,
    "Legs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$Route.Legs",
        "as": "l",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [    
            { "$gte": [
              "$$l.LegId",
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": { 
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$Route.Legs",
                      "as": "l",
                      "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$l.StartAddress", "Nittambuwa" ] },
                          { "$eq": [
                            { "$size": {
                              "$setIntersection": [ [ "Kegalle" ], "$$l.Ancestors" ]
                            }},
                            0
                          ]}
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "as": "l",
                  "in": "$$l.LegId"
                }},
                0
              ]}
            ]},
            { "$lte": [ "$$l.LegId", 3 ] }  
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You cannot really apply such things as [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) here to fetch the array index, because of the "multiple conditions" required to match the array element.

Whilst there is not a "direct" equivalence to [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) as a "logical operator" for an aggregation condition, you can use alternatives. Here I apply [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) as it's probably the best to compare two "unique" arrays. The logic says when the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the "intersection" is `0`, there there was no match. Thus meeting the same criteria as [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/).

Of course the "multiple" conditions are all wrapped by [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/and/), since that is what it does.

The result of course filters the array items between the `"LegId"` value that matched the conditions, and the "end" value supplied, which is `3`:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597c48d222b29fc421e82d20"),
    "RiderId" : "DEMO",
    "Legs" : [ 
        {
            "LegId" : 1.0,
            "Distance" : 18008.0,
            "Duration" : 1850.0,
            "Price" : "480",
            "StartAddress" : "Nittambuwa",
            "StartLocation" : [ 
                7.1420863, 
                80.1038061
            ],
            "EndAddress" : "Warakapola",
            "EndLocation" : [ 
                7.2268383, 
                80.1959644
            ],
            "Ancestors" : [ 
                "Colombo"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "LegId" : 2.0,
            "Distance" : 22478.0,
            "Duration" : 2208.0,
            "Price" : "720",
            "StartAddress" : "Warakapola",
            "StartLocation" : [ 
                7.2268383, 
                80.1959644
            ],
            "EndAddress" : "Kegalle",
            "EndLocation" : [ 
                7.2514362, 
                80.3466076
            ],
            "Ancestors" : [ 
                "Colombo", 
                "Nittambuwa"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

All copied and pasted from the data supplied and results of the statement issued here.

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed explanation. especially the alternatives for $in and the using of $map gave me some good ideas for few other queries too :)